# Android audio stuck on bottom speaker and can not use headphones in my application.App also freezes

Tags: java, android, audio, webrtc, speaker

We are developing a native application using webrtc,kurento media server and nubomedia libraries for video and audio conferences. We are in the point where we can receive video and audio from other applicants.

The problem we got is that sometimes when we make a connection the audio starts very loud and only from the bottom speaker of the phone and we can't turn it down or insert headphones cause it has no effect. This usually recovers after i give a restart to the phone but can appear randomly when i enter the app again. Normally the sound comes from the from speaker when it works fine.I can post some code if it helps but it's just a lot and i don't know what exactly could be the problem. Could it be some webrtc bug or a bug in our app even if i cant seem to reproduce it. Is there a way i can block the bottom speaker.

Also the application freezes sometimes on start up with no error message or anything, I ques it could be some memory leaks,any way to track that down? Really sorry for the long post.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC will play the audio(Remote Audio Track) in default output device (ear-piece/speaker/headphone/Bluetooth), you can choose one from your application.
Whatever the changes you made from your app will effect to all other apps running on that device and vice versa.

You need to extend the [Android AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to switch output devices automatically during the call.
Eg: Loud speaker for videocall/Ringtone, Ear-piece for audio call/proximity & headset/Bluetooth when they connected.

Use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to get event triggers.
See AppRTC [AudioManager](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp/src/org/appspot/apprtc/AppRTCAudioManager.java) & [Bluetooth Manager](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp/src/org/appspot/apprtc/AppRTCBluetoothManager.java) for reference.

**Note:**  Make sure you need to reset the output device, when call is finished or before your app exits. Otherwise it will effect other apps.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply. I did manage to resolve the audio problem by using a broadcast receiver and audio manager to switch back to the front speaker, but for some reason sometimes the audio just switches back to loud speaker on its own, and its very randomly